# Set locale for Here autocomplete api (and reverse geocoding)

Tags: android, maps, here-api

Can I specify a locale/language for the Here api ?
For example I'm looking for "Rue du corail Casablanca Maroc/Morocco" I have no results but if I use the reverse geocoding with the position `33.5962134,-7.6644365`, I have results in arabic, but I want results in french or an other language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding not getting any results, it's probably just autocomplete API issue, because when I try to use [Geocoding API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/dev_guide/topics/resource-geocode.html) I get the response.

Regarding getting response in different language, you can simply add "language" parameter to both of your requests, for example for spanish results add:

`&language=es`

For more information see [Reverse Geocode](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/dev_guide/topics/resource-reverse-geocode.html) and [Autocomplete API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder-autocomplete/dev_guide/topics/resource-suggest.html) documentations

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see all these Request Parameters